# Ionic 2 Promise return __zone_symbol__value array[]

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I`m using Ionic 2 and I have a provider for the http request.

This is the code I use for make the http request to the server.

```
Api_get(data?){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
         this.http.post(this.url + data.method, data.send).subscribe(data =>{
             resolve( data.json() );
             reject({status:false});
         })
     })

  }
```

The request is done but when I see the logs the result is this object __zone_symbol__value array[2] inside the object are there the results of the request.

I don´t know if i`m doing something wrong hope you can help me.

Answer (score -2):

angular `http` default return `Observable` you should use Observable to return your API data. You don't really need to wrap your http request with a Promise.

Also you can use `.map` right after to convert your data into json format.

Try the following code instead.

```
Api_get(data?) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + data.method, data.send).map(res=>res.json());
}

//collecting the return data
requestData() {
  var data = {1,2,3}; //example of data
    this.Api_get(data).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, for Observable you do not need to use resolve(), also had an typo on the work subscribe. Check the edited example.